# how to get array element in javaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a problem with JavaScript,
I have an array that get from model in controller and send it from controller to view like : echo json_encode($data);
when i printed console.log(data) in view I got data like :

```
[{"id":"1","u_name":"07991111111"}]
```

Now I want to get the specific data like user_name.
how can i get ?

I tried

```
console.log(data.user_name)
```

Comment: Did you try `data[0].u_name`?

Comment: user_name != u_name

Comment: First of all  there is `no property name` like `user_name` . and try  @SpencerWieczorek suggested  comment .

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

That is `data[0]`

```
alert(data[0].id) // "1"
alert(data[0].u_name) // "07991111111"
```

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
var data=[{"id":"1","u_name":"07991111111"}];
var id=data[0].id;
var name=data[0].u_name;

console.log('id',id);
console.log('name',name);
```

if data is more than `0` like

```
var data=[{"id":"1","u_name":"07991111111"},
          {"id":"2","u_name":"07991111112"}
         ];
```

than you will access that array object like this

```
var id1=data[0].id;
var id2=data[1].id;
```

Comment: still can not get data.

Comment: @kajab is there any Error??

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

var obj = JSON.parse('{"id":"1","u_name":"07991111111"}');

console.log(obj.id);

console.log(obj.u_name);